# R: Restricted permutations more efficient way than using for loops

Tags: r, for-loop, recursion

I am trying to permute a char vector `a` of variable length picking 3 elements every time, without repetition. Ordering counts only for the first element but doesn't for second and third (e.g. abc != bac != cab, but abc = acb and bca = bac). Each set of 3 permuted elements should be a row in a dataframe `b`.

A vector with letters *a*,*b*,*c*,*d*,*e* would result in this expected output:

```
abc
abd
abe
acd
ace
ade

bac
bad
bae
bcd
bce
bde

cab 
cad
cae
cbd
cbe
cde

dab
dac
dae
dbc
dbe
dce

eab
eac
ead
ebc
ebd
ecd
```

Using 3 for loops I think I was able to achieve this output, but it is slow if the vector is long.

```r
a = letters[1:5]
aL = length(a)
b <- data.frame(var1 = character(),
                var2 = character(), 
                var3 = character(), 
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 


# restricted permutations for moderation
pracma::tic()
for(i in 1:aL){
  for(j in 1:(aL-1)){
    for(k in (j+1):aL){
      if(j != i & k != i) { 
        b <- rbind(b, data.frame(a[i], a[j], a[k])) }
    }
  }
}
pracma::toc()
#> elapsed time is 0.070000 seconds
b
#>    a.i. a.j. a.k.
#> 1     a    b    c
#> 2     a    b    d
#> 3     a    b    e
#> 4     a    c    d
#> 5     a    c    e
#> 6     a    d    e
#> 7     b    a    c
#> 8     b    a    d
#> 9     b    a    e
#> 10    b    c    d
#> 11    b    c    e
#> 12    b    d    e
#> 13    c    a    b
#> 14    c    a    d
#> 15    c    a    e
#> 16    c    b    d
#> 17    c    b    e
#> 18    c    d    e
#> 19    d    a    b
#> 20    d    a    c
#> 21    d    a    e
#> 22    d    b    c
#> 23    d    b    e
#> 24    d    c    e
#> 25    e    a    b
#> 26    e    a    c
#> 27    e    a    d
#> 28    e    b    c
#> 29    e    b    d
#> 30    e    c    d
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

How can I achieve the same outcome in less time. Is recursion faster?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It seems that he doesnt want replications of the type "aab" or "bbb". All element in his exmples consist of three different letters, so ``` expand.grid(a, a, a)``` doesnt do the trick. You have to find a way to omit such unwanted rows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I propose the following solution:

```
a = letters[1:5]
A = t(combn(a,3)) # create all possible three-letter combinations, 
                  # disregarding the order 
Full = rbind(A, A[,3:1], A[,c(2,3,1)]) # put every of the elements of the 
                                       # differing combinations in first place once
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option for your specific example:

```
library(gtools)
library(dplyr)

# example vector
vec = letters[1:5]

# vectorised function to rearrange elements (based on your restriction)
f = function(x1,x2,x3) paste0(c(x1, sort(c(x2,x3))), collapse = " ")
f = Vectorize(f)

permutations(length(vec), 3, vec) %>%      # get permutations
  data.frame(., stringsAsFactors = F) %>%  # save as data frame
  mutate(vec = f(X1,X2,X3)) %>%            # apply function to each row
  distinct(vec, .keep_all = T)             # keep distinct vec values

#    X1 X2 X3   vec
# 1   a  b  c a b c
# 2   a  b  d a b d
# 3   a  b  e a b e
# 4   a  c  d a c d
# 5   a  c  e a c e
# 6   a  d  e a d e
# 7   b  a  c b a c
# ...
```

Not clear if you want your output to be 3 separate columns with 1 element each, or one column with the vector, so I'm keeping both for you to choose from. You can keep columns `{X1, X2, X3}` or just `vec`.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a straightforward rewrite of the triple `for` loop as a triple `lapply` loop.

```
t1 <- system.time({
for(i in 1:aL){
  for(j in 1:(aL-1)){
    for(k in (j+1):aL){
      if(j != i & k != i) { 
        b <- rbind(b, data.frame(a[i], a[j], a[k])) }
    }
  }
}
})

t2 <- system.time({
d <- lapply(1:aL, function(i){
  tmp <- lapply(1:(aL-1), function(j){
    tmp <- lapply((j+1):aL, function(k){
      if(j != i & k != i) c(a[i], a[j], a[k])
    })
    do.call(rbind, tmp)
  })
  do.call(rbind, tmp)
})
d <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, d)
names(d) <- paste("a", 1:3, sep = ".")
})

all.equal(b, d)
#[1] "Names: 3 string mismatches"

rbind(t1, t2)
#   user.self sys.self elapsed user.child sys.child
#t1     0.051        0   0.051          0         0
#t2     0.017        0   0.018          0         0
```